# ¿Como dividir un double sobre 10 para desplazarme un dígito a la derecha?

Tags: c++, double

estoy tratando de dividir un double de la siguiente manera:

```
double h = 10000;
for(int i=0; i<50; i++){
   h /= 10;
}
```

en algún momento en vez de arrojar ***0,0...01*** me esta arrojando ***1,0...0337124408*** y un montón de basura pero se supone que no debería arrojar esto ya que solo se divide sobre 10 y el 1 debería correr una posición a la derecha.

Comment: Gracias ya lo resolvi